# Showing column from referenced table in list view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am a complete novice in ASP.NET MVC with just 1 days of experience so far.

I am trying to show a list of employees along with their departments. I have separate tables for employees and departments  (I am using Entity Framework 6 and Database First architecture).

[image]

This is the code generated from the database.

```
public partial class employee
{
    public int employeeid { get; set; }
    public string employeename { get; set; }
    public string designation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> departmentid { get; set; }

    public virtual department department { get; set; }
}
```

In my employees controller, I have this code for my index page

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IQueryable<employee> employees = db.employees
            .Include(d => d.department);

        return View(employees.ToList());
    }
```

And in my Razor view, I have this code segment

```
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.employeename)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.designation)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.department.departmentname)
    </td>
```

However, when I run the application, the department name is showing blank. The other fields are being displayed correctly.

Note: I can insert an employee using a dropdown for departments, as shown in the screenshot. I just do not understand why the list view mode is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh no I made a very stupid mistake.

In the parameter list of my Create method of the controller, departmentid was missing.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "employeeid,employeename,designation,departmentid")] employee employee)
```

I noticed it after I checked the database from SQL Server Studio and saw that departmentid field was being saved as NULL.

Moreover, I realized that instead of

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IQueryable<employee> employees = db.employees
        .Include(d => d.department);

    return View(employees.ToList());
}
```

only the following code was enough

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.employees.ToList());
    }
```